# Spring Boot Application is failing to start

Tags: spring-boot

A simple spring boot application is failing to start by giving the below error, I'm unable to understand what is going on. I have created with spring starter spring boot version 1.5.6 release starting the newly created project giving me this error before two days it was working.

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_45\bin\java" -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,
address=127.0.0.1:50709,suspend=y,server=n org.sounds.bvs.SoundsApplication 
--spring.output.ansi.enabled=always
Connected to the target VM, address: '127.0.0.1:50709', transport: 'socket'
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.


Process finished with exit code 1
```

**pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.sounds</groupId>
<artifactId>SoundsApplication</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>SoundsApplication</name>
<description>Background Verification Project in Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please post your entire stack trace

Comment: NO Stack trace that is my issue. the first three statements then the spring boot logo then exit status if i had stack trace i would have resolved.

Comment: But when i do a mvn clean, install and java -jar this will work perfectly i never faced this issue.

Comment: It's quite difficult to tell from this much information. Please show the dependencies and other code

Comment: The project is in its initial stage fresh project and its default pom.xml is below

Comment: <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.6.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

<dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

Comment: Please include this pom in the question, Also can you post a link to your entire project? I'll look into it

Comment: These are minimal when we use starter project this is only failing me and its bit confusing also.

Comment: I tried a simple Spring boot app with your pom and its working fine. I put the code on github: https://github.com/mansi2392/SpringBootDemo

Comment: Make sure using a process explorer that when you kill the application from the IDE, that the java process actualy dies.

Comment: solved the issue it was issue with the maven configuration and .m2 was corrupted so rebuilding the index solved the issue thank you both.